# how to update like this? (SQL)

Tags: sql

I have 3 databases: service1, businessrecord, and teamAstaffno

1)I want to identify the the service type in two type "play" and "mainbusiness" and "error"

-if businessrecord.type like "play" as "play"

-if businessrecord.other match service1.servicetype as "mainbusiness"

-if it fulfill two option should show "error"

2) I am just want the business record which match teamAstaffno.staffno only, because I just want team A record.

3) finally, I want a table which have the cloumn order_type to show "play", "mainbusiness", "error" and "duplicate"

than, what will be the sql code?

and I type like this

```
    select businessrecord.type, businessrecord.other, businessrecord.staffno;
from service1;
    join  businessrecord;
        on businessrecord.other = service1.servicetype;
    inner join teamAstaffno;
        on businessrecord.staffno = teamAstaffno.staffno
```

and the record copy into table proc1

```
alter table proc1 add order_type Char(50) 
update order_type with "mainbusiness" where businessrecord.type like service1.servicetype
update order_type with "duplicate" where order_type like "mainbusiness" and type like "play"
update order_type with "play" where other like "play" 
update order_type with "Error" where order_type is null
```

what am I doing wrong?

if the  was using two table should I use join function and how is the code?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle? Did you try reading the manual for your DBMS? They usually explain in quite detail what the exact detail of the `update` statement is.

Answer (score 1):

Your `UPDATE` syntax is incorrect

```
UPDATE <tablename>
SET <columnname> = <somevalue>
WHERE <predicate>
```

Some dbms' let you do a join for your update

```
UPDATE alias1
SET alias1.column = 'somevalue'
FROM table1 alias1
JOIN table2 alias2 ON alias1.ID = alias2.ForeignID
WHERE alias2.SomeColumn = 'blah'
```

Comment: if the <predicate> was using two table..... should I use join function and how is the code....?

Comment: @user2853152 I updated the answer to contain the syntax for update using joins

Answer (score 0):

If you need a join in the WHERE statement, you can do it like this:

```
UPDATE     t1
SET        Col2 = t2.Col2,
           Col3 = t2.Col3,
           Col4 = t2.Col4,
FROM       Table1 t1
INNER JOIN Table2 t2 ON t1.Col1 = t2.Col1
WHERE      t1.Col1 = 'whatever' 
AND        t2.Col3 = 'somethingelse'
```

So in your case I would guess it's something like this:

```
UPDATE      service1
SET         OrderType = (CASE 
                WHEN businessrecord.type = service1.servicetype THEN 'mainbusiness'
                WHEN order_type = 'mainbusiness' and type = 'play' THEN 'duplicate'
                WHEN other = 'play' THEN 'play'
                WHEN order_type IS NULL THEN 'Error'
            END)
FROM        service1
INNER JOIN  businessrecord
ON          businessrecord.other = service1.servicetype
INNER JOIN  teamAstaffno
ON          businessrecord.staffno = teamAstaffno.staffno
```

NOTE: This may not be exactly what you want, but at least it shows you how to do the conditional updates using a `CASE` statement.

See the MSDN documentation here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx